# Macbook charger isn't working

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

My MacBook charger is supposed to pass 60 watts power, but it's passing only around 12 watts.  Also, the green LED just blinks randomly.

Should I get a new charger or something can be done to existing one?

Comment: How did you get the reading? What is the color of the LED in the charger when it's in use?

Comment: I got the reading from macbook's hardware test. Green LED just blinks randomly.

Comment: We're missing a bunch of details here like Model and year of your MacBook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Green LED just blinks randomly.

**This is most likely an issue with the DC-In or your logic board.**

This is an error condition caused by a fault that is detected between your MagSafe and the power circuitry.  There's a small possibility that the issue is your charger, but it's highly unlikely.  The easiest way to test is to take your MacBook to Apple and hook up one of their chargers - if the blinking persists, it's your DC-in board or your logic board.

If it's your DC-in board, the procedure to fix is is pretty easy and is a DIY.  Depending on the model of your Mac, the DC-in board may be integrated into the logic board itself; which means you will have to take it in for service.

If happens to be your charger, then you will need to replace it with another - there are no user serviceable components.  Be sure to get a genuine adapter and not a knock off.  I've seen way too many times the result of being "penny wise and pound foolish."

Comment: Thanks @Allan, my macbook gets charged by another charger, so I doubt if there is anything wrong with Macbook.

Comment: If the symptoms go away, it's your charger (which, in my experience, is rare).  You just need to get a new charger and you should be good to go (get a genuine Apple - not 3rd party...too risky)

Comment: Yes @Allan, I should get genuine Apple only. With the third party, reviews are not good.

Answer (score 1):

Is your MacBook charging up properly when you are using it with the charger plugged in?

It might only be drawing 12W of power because your batteries are fully charged and the 12W is only used for your current operation.

Having a charger capable of giving 60W does not mean your MacBook will always require 60W from it.

For example, my MacBook Pro is currently drawing 20.31 V from the power adapter right now.

[image]

Comment: No macbook is not charging, with the charger

Comment: @KishorPawar then your charger (or macbook) is broken. Visit your nearest Apple Store for a checkup.

Comment: Nothing broken. Out of nothing  I started experiencing this issue

Comment: The only thing unusual is, I stay in a area where electricity is irregular.

Comment: @KishorPawar Oh, when you say "Macbook is not charging" you meant your macbook's battery is full so it is not charging?

Then refer to what I said in the answer: "It might only be drawing 12W of power because your batteries are fully charged and the 12W is only used for your current operation."

Comment: @KishorPawar for example, my macbook pro is currently only using 20V of power right now. (updated answer with photo)

Comment: Macbook is not charging when even it is drained fully

Comment: @KishorPawar if your MacBook is not charging when it is drained fully, doesn't that means it's broken? What do you mean by "Nothing broken" then?

Comment: Man it's charging with other chargers... And nothing broken as in nothing is physically dmamaged

Comment: @KishorPawar then your adapter is broken. It is not charging up your Mac. You should replace it. If it is still under warranty, you should go to Apple store to exchange for a functional one. When I said it is "broken", I meant it is "not functioning as intended", regardless of its "physical" condition.

Comment: @KishorPawar glad it helps. please mark this as answer ;)

Comment: Man it did not help. You told me the same thing which I said in my question. I knew my charger is not working. I asked what should I do with that?

Comment: haha. sorry.

you should get a new one or get it replaced if it is still under warranty.

Comment: You can open up the charger if you know electronics, but you are risking your Mac here as it might over charge blow your Mac...